# Converting to machine precision

Tags: numerics

There are multiple ways to convert an expression to machine precision, for example:

```
In[1]:= a = Sqrt[2]
Out[1]= Sqrt[2]

In[2]:= {1.a, 1`a, N@a, SetPrecision[a,MachinePrecision]}
Out[2]= {1.41421,1.41421,1.41421,1.41421}

In[3]:= Precision /@ %
Out[3]= {MachinePrecision,MachinePrecision,MachinePrecision,MachinePrecision}
```

My question is whether or not these methods are absolutely equivalent. Is it just a matter of personal taste which one to use, or are there examples where they behave differently?

Comment: You can also use ``Developer`ToPackedArray[{1, Sqrt[2], 3, 4}, Real]`` to create machine precision numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of speed `N` and `SetPrecision` can be expected to be faster as they do not involve an unnecessary multiplication.  (Conversely `` 2` * a `` would be better than `N[2 * a]` because the latter does exact multiplication before the conversion.)

---

`1. a` and `` 1` a `` can be considered identical because they represent the same input.  Personally I have taken to using the latter form for entering machine-precision integers because the syntax better reminds me of the purpose.

---

One can see that `N` and `SetPrecision[#, MachinePrecision] &` are, if not equivalent, closely related.  Observe:

```
N[thing] := 17.5

NValues[thing]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[N[thing, {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}]] :> 17.5}
> ```

Now:

```
N[thing]

SetPrecision[thing, MachinePrecision]
```

> ```
> 17.5
>
> 17.5
> ```

The fact that `NValues` output is given from `SetPrecision` indicates to me that it is using a common mechanism.

On-the-fly conversion does not use `NValues`:

```
1. thing

2` + thing
```

> ```
> 1. thing
>
> 2. + thing
> ```

---

Here is another demonstrable difference between `N`/`SetPrecision` and multiplication by `1.`:

```
N[ Exp[1000] ]                            // Precision

SetPrecision[Exp[1000], MachinePrecision] // Precision

1. Exp[1000]                              // Precision
```

> ```
> 12.9546
>
> 12.9546
>
> 15.9546
> ```

Comment: `N` also does some caching or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ajasja I don't know, but I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Here is the relevant example http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearSystemCache.html

Comment: @Ajasja that kind of caching is not specific to `N`.  Try: ``1`1000000 Pi; // Timing`` twice.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks. I like the idea of using the backtick form as a reminder of the purpose. I think it looks a bit neater than `1.` too (I always want to add a zero after the decimal point even though I know it isn't necessary)