# Confused by (apparent) inconsistent precision

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, faq

$$ e^{\pi \sqrt{163}} \approx 262537412640768743.99999999999925 $$

```
E^(Pi Sqrt[163.0])
N[E^(Pi Sqrt[163.0]), 35]
NumberForm[E^(Pi Sqrt[163.]), 35]
```

returns

```
2.6253741*10^17
2.6253741*10^17
2.625374126407682*10^17
```

That's not the 35 digits I expected. OTOH,

```
N[Pi* E, 35]
```

returns 35 digits,

```
8.5397342226735670654635508695465745
```

but then

```
NumberForm[Pi*E*1., 35]
```

again doesn't:

```
8.53973422267357
```

So I'm confused. Why doesn't one `N[]` what the other one does? In the documentation:

> **NumberForm**[ *expr*, *n* ]
>        prints with approximate real numbers in *expr* given to *n*-digit precision.

I read this three times, slowly, went for a cup of tea, and read it again. But 15 isn't 35, or is it?

Comment: It is, for sufficiently large values of... Okay, the issue, as stated in the response below, is that you cannot get more correct digits after the fact. To obtain 35 digits, use N[] on an exact input, not one that already contains approximate numbers of lower precision.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks for the feedback. Are you referring to my `163.0` instead of `163`? To be honest, I don't know why I wrote it that way :-/

Comment: Yes, I meant 163.0 was, in effect, polluting the input with machine precision.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The documentation states](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html#570568123):

> N does not raise the precision of approximate numbers in its input

`163.0` (or `163.`, or `` 163` ``) is a machine precision number, and *Mathematica* will not fake a higher precision when a certain number of digits are requested with `N`.

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3153/121) and [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html) for more.

These questions may also be of interest:

[Converting to machine precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7564/121)

[Annoying display truncation of numerical results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121)

Comment: @stevenvh In keeping with Mr.Wizard's advice, you may wish to compare using `163` (without the decimal point) in your code.