# User defined functions and decimal places displayed

Tags: functions, precision-and-accuracy

I have a couple of complicated user-defined functions, one which calls the other, and I wish to control the number of decimal places displayed when I call the "mother" function. I have tried the obvious

```
N[mother[],n]
```

but no matter the choice for n I receive only 6 decimal places. But when I write a simple nested function like

```
f[x_] := Module[{}, x/3];
g[x_] := Module[{}, f[x]];
```

and then call

```
N[g[1], 50]
```

I receive the requested number of digits (so it doesn't seem to be the nesting causing the issue). Unfortunately I cannot post the actual functions I am playing with due to their size. Any ideas would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question is a combination of these:

- [Annoying display truncation of numerical results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121)
- [Confused by (apparent) inconsistent precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121)
- [A problem about function N](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/121)

Specifically, for your function to work as desired most directly (and correctly) it will need to return a number or expression in *arbitrary precision*.  This is (best) done by using arbitrary precision or exact numbers throughout the computation.

Alternately you can use [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) to display your output rather than `N`.

The result can be forced with [`SetAccuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAccuracy.html) with the understanding that your results are fake.  See:

- [Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121)