# N[..., 5] does not returns what I expected

Tags: numerics, output-formatting, numerical-value

I have this

```
Xt = 
  {{1., 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
   {1, 1.5, 1.5,1.5, 2, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5, 2.8, 2.8, 3, 3, 3.2, 3.3}};
Yt = 
  {101.4, 117.4, 117.1, 106.2, 131.9, 146.9, 146.8, 133.9, 111.3, 123, 125.1, 145.2, 134.3, 144.5, 143.7, 146.9};

N[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt, 5]
```

and the last evaluation returns the same result as if there was no `N[..,..]`; i.e.,

> `{93.3422, 15.6485}`

Why and how do I get output to five decimals?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! Generally we try to only use the "bugs" tag once other users have verified that a function is not working the way the documentation suggests it should.

Comment: well no one told me about it.. I'll edit :).

Comment: It's no problem! I just thought I'd leave a comment for future reference. I had no idea that's how it worked when I first started here either!

Comment: One thing every Mathematica user must learn is that the 2nd argument of `N` has no effect on machine precision numbers, which are the kind of numbers you are using.

Comment: I think you might find reading [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99219/3066) helps your understanding of `N`, which is a more sophisticated function than most beginners think it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one solution.

```
Xt = Rationalize@{{1., 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     1}, {1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5, 2.8, 2.8, 3, 3, 
     3.2, 3.3}};
Yt = Rationalize@{101.4, 117.4, 117.1, 106.2, 131.9, 146.9, 146.8, 
    133.9, 111.3, 123, 125.1, 145.2, 134.3, 144.5, 143.7, 146.9};
Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt
```

> $\left\{\frac{892351}{9560},\frac{3740}{239}\right\}$

```
N[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt, 5]
```

> {93.342, 15.649}

```
N[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt, 10]
```

> {93.34215481, 15.64853556}

Answer (score 8):

The documentation for `N` says that `N[expr, n]` attempts to give a result with n-digit precision. In the Wolfram Language, or any language, precision is not the same as decimal places. While it might seem like `N` is there to give us results with a certain number of decimal places, it actually has more to do with the amount of precision used in calculations behind the scenes. It can be especially confusing as sometimes `N` does close to what we expect as in `N[Pi, 10]` which gives us $\pi$ with 10 digits (9 decimal places).

There is a different function called `NumberForm` that is designed to let us have more control over the display of numbers.

We can use:

```
NumberForm[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt].Xt.Yt, {20, 5}]
```

yields

> {93.34215, 15.64854}

The first number in `NumberForm` (i.e. 20) is the total number of digits. We can set this to Infinity and it won't make a difference, but it shouldn't be less than the total number of digits you want to display. The second number (i.e. 5) is the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html#731903681):

> MachinePrecision is considered less precise than any other precision. This is because, while machine-precision numbers always store slightly under 16 digits, no specific number of those digits are known to be correct.

We're working with `MachinePrecision`, i.e.

```
Precision[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt]
```

> ```
> MachinePrecision
> ```

and so `N[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt, 5]` needs to somehow *upsample* the precision of the result and that is an ill-defined operation.

In fact the ref page for [N](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html#14398) states

> Unless numbers in expr are exact, or of sufficiently high precision, N[expr, n] may not be able to give results with n-digit precision.

To see why this is ill-defined, consider the reverse. Let's go from higher precision to lower precision.

```
x1 = N[Pi, 10]
```

> $3.1415926{\color{red}5}4$

```
x2 = N[Pi + 10^-8, 10]
```

> $3.1415926{\color{red}6}4$

```
N[{x1, x2}, 5]
```

> {3.1416, 3.1416}

So we see if we reverse this example, going from precision 5 to precision 10 is ambiguous in the choices of the 6th - 10th digits.

---

If you'd like to upsample in a consistent way, use [`SetPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html#5106):

> When SetPrecision is used to increase the precision of a number, the number is padded with zeros. The zeros are taken to be in base 2. In base 10, the additional digits are usually not zeros.

```
SetPrecision[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt, 5]
```

> ```
> {93.342, 15.649}
> ```

If you only care about the display of the answer, consider using [`NumberForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html):

```
NumberForm[Inverse[Xt.Transpose[Xt]].Xt.Yt, 5]
```

> ```
> {93.342, 15.649}
> ```