# Showing more decimals in number calculated in While loop

Tags: number-representation

I'm new to Mathematica and am not sure why I cannot show more decimal points in a variable. I am using Newton's Method to find the zero's of a function and I'm trying to print the x value of the zero.

```
f[x_] := Tan[x] - x/2;
fp[x_] := -1/2 + Sec[x]^2;
xn = 5.;
convergence = False;
\[Epsilon] = 1*^-6;
fx = f[xn];
While[convergence == False,
 fpx = fp[xn];
 d = fx/fpx;
 xn = xn - d;
 fx = f[xn];
 If[Abs[d] < \[Epsilon], convergence = True]]
N[xn, 10]
N[5, 10]
```

Which returns:

```
39.219
5.000000000
```

the zero is at 39.219, but I believe there are more decimals in this, and wanted to just test the N[] function with 5 to make sure that it will just print 0's after the number if there are not more numbers. Why is it only showing 5 numbers for xn?

Comment: This doesn't look right. According to the documentation it should work. I tried a workaround with `SetPrecision[xn,10]` and it printed `39.21895656` (Nice workaround yaay!) I'll have to look a bit into this before posting an answer.

Comment: `N` only works when the specified amount of digits can be found correctly. Using `MachinePrecision` numbers such as `xn` is like naively assuming 15.95 correct digits at any time, which doesn't provide the guarantee that `N` wants.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of either or both: [(3736)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121), [(10624)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121).  Also related: [(55292)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, even though intuitively this looks like something that should work, it doesn't. This is because of the way *Mathematica* handles precision. You might have noticed that you can output really large numbers like *10^10000* which are way beyond `MachinePrecision` of `double`. This is because *Mathematica* is a symbolic language. Each value gets it's precision which you can look at by calling `Precision[a]` Symbols, Integers and some other stuff has $\infty$ precision and some things have `MachinePrecision`. It is written in the documentation that

> N[e] typically works by replacing numbers with machine numbers and computing the result.

and that:

> The precision of the result is the same as that of the input:

This means if you have machine precision it will `N` will always return the same precision. In your sanity check if you wrote

`N[5.,10]` instead of `N[5,10]` you would get `5.`

Now you can change the precision by using `SetPrecision` as I did in the comment and things will go smoother.

**EDIT**

Also `N` Will try to give you the result that can be *Exactly* computed without machine errors. So there's also that.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me to be a tempest in a teapot. If you just want to see the what `xn` looks like in its full internal glory, evaluate

```
xn // FullForm
```

which gives

> `` 39.21895655961492` ``

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: instead

```
N[xn, 10]
```

> 39.219

type

```
SetAccuracy[xn, 10]
```

> 39.2189565596

Comment: Can you elaborate more in your answer, what's the difference between `SetAccuracy` and and `SetPrecision`?

Comment: `SetPrecision[xn, 10]` gives 10 digits: `39.21895656`; `SetAccuracy[xn, 10]` gives 10 digits _after the decimal point_:`39.2189565596`.