# Convert Integer to Real

Tags: conversion, number-representation

Is there a preferred way of converting an `Integer` to a `Real`?

What I'm using at the moment is `x + 0.0`.

Comment: [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html) is what I use.

Comment: @MichaelE2 your chance to post a canonical answer using one character ;-)

Comment: Although the answer *is* trivial, there is no one-hit wonder on google or in the documentation. The first immediately useful hit is http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v2/contents/3.1.2.pdf, which is already running under "legacy", so I would vote against closure as long as @MichaelE2 posts his comment as answer.

Comment: @yvesklett I was about to vote to close, but you're right, unfortunately. I have been trying to find an answer to this question as if I were a newbie. There just doesnt seem to be an easy and intuitive way a new user could arrive at the answer, at least not from the online documentation.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries my first reflex was also to close (as in quite a few cases these last days). It may be a duplicate, but in fact this title question and the straightforward answer may be even more useful for newbies.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard even though though the answer to the referenced question applies here. the question is not the same, insofar as it deals with nuances of converting (and presumes the knowledge of `N`), not the straightforward way to do so.

Comment: @Yves You do not appear to be disagreeing with "This question already has an answer here:" which is as it is marked.  Would you rather this question be closed as "easily found in the documentation," or reopened?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry for the ambiguity. I feel like this question might merit reopening, and would cast my vote thusly, unless someone (you?) feels like making the case for a real dupe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html)

---

A one-character answer is disallowed by SE, so I will expand.  `N` is mostly what I use.  If I have an expression like $2 x + 3$, I sometimes write it `2. x + 3.` in *Mathematica*; then if `x` is numeric, whether it happens to be an `Integer` or not, the expression will always be `Real` or `Complex`.

Comment: Indeed, the last part of the statement is always true, my bad. Well... actually, if `x` is *something completely different*..... :)

Comment: Michael, it seems to me that this question may be considered a duplicate of [(7564)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7564/121).  Since you have the Accepted answer here what do you think?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, they seem sufficiently close to be called duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
Head /@ {23, 23*1, 23/1, 23 + 0, 23., 23*1., 23/1., 23 + 0.}
```

> {Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Real, Real, Real, Real}

Answer (score 0):

This also

```
{Head[1], Head[1 // N]}
```

{Integer, Real}

Answer (score -3):

`Real` is the best way to convert an integer into a real as shown by the following.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  Real[i];
  ,{j,1,10^6}]]
(* {1.881108,Null}
```

Knowing that the part i = 1; takes some time by itself.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[ 
  i = 1;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {1.216070, Null}

it means that converting one million 1 to 1. takes 0.665038 s.
```

All other ways are significantly longer. The method using `N` being a very slow method.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i*1.0;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {2.042117, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i*1.;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {2.043117, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i + 0.0;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {2.080119, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i + 0.;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {2.082119, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i^1.0;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {3.199183, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i^1.;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {3.207183, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  N[i];
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {3.459198, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i/1.;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {3.626207, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  i = 1;
  i/1.0;
  , {j, 1, 10^6}]]
(* {3.662209, Null} *)
```

It means that converting one million 1 to 1. by `N` takes 2.24313 s, thus 3.37293 times longer than using `Real`. It can have a significant effect in some programs.

Comment: This has some good content but the formatting hurts the eyes.

Comment: Because this is your 1st post, I have edited your answer so it complies with the formatting guidelines of this site. I hope you will take some time to study those guidelines and adhere to them in future posts.

Comment: In version 10.1.0 `Real[1]` does not evaluate further.  In other words it does not change an Integer into a Real.  Is this different on your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ditto for 10.4.1, 9.0.1, and 8.0.4.

Comment: Well I guess this answer is incorrect. I tested in version 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Comment: `Real` isnt even a function..best make sure something works before testing timing