# Complex result for real vectors in VectorAngle

Tags: numerics, bugs, complex, vector

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0.0 or earlier**

---

I was expecting a real angle using `VectorAngle` when passing real valued vectors, but I obtained a complex angle:

```
VectorAngle[{-2.7432000000000016`, 0.`, 0.`},{2.743199999999973`, 0.`, 0.`}]
```

returns

```
3.14159 - 2.10734*10^-8 I
```

I was expecting `3.14159` ($\pi$) as this is essentially a half circle. My guess is the precision of the numbers results in the imaginary portion.

3 possible solutions are:

- using `Round[result, 10^-7]`, which works for this case, but future cases might have an imaginary part larger than $10^{-8}$
- using `Re[result]`, a better solution.

Interestingly, using `Round` on the vectors to some sufficiently small value results in an exact solution. For example I rounded to the nearest `10^-100` and got the exact value of $\pi$.

Going forward I'll probably just take the real part of the result, but is this the expected behavior in *Mathematica* for this function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this is one of the many manifestations of machine precision arithmetic in *Mathematica*, and it appears because `VectorAngle` also works with complex values.  If you use the arbitrary precision engine, these cancellation errors should not occur:

```
 VectorAngle[{-2.7432`12, 0, 0}, {2.7432`12, 0, 0}]
```

> ```
> 3.14159
> ```

Note the `` `12 `` on the numbers; this sets a precision of 12 digits.  Perhaps more applicable to your situation, you can use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html) (or [`SetAccuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetAccuracy.html)) on existing data to convert it to arbitrary precision:

```
in = {{-2.7432000000000016`, 0.`, 0.`}, {2.743199999999973`, 0.`, 0.`}};

VectorAngle @@ SetPrecision[in, 12]
```

> ```
> 3.14159
> ```

Likewise, using exact arithmetic will avoid this problem as you already note:

```
VectorAngle @@ Rationalize[in]
```

> ```
> π
> ```

Please see the second part of this answer for an introduction to machine and arbitrary precision in *Mathematica* in my own words:

- [Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/funny-behaviour-when-plotting-a-polynomial-of-high-degree-and-large-coefficients/3153#3153)

Recommended reading:

- [Annoying display truncation of numerical results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121)
- [Confused by (apparent) inconsistent precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10624/121)
- [Converting to machine precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7564/121)

Comment: @Adam You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 16):

Just found this. This is probably a good opportunity to demonstrate the importance of using a numerically stable formula.

I will use a simpler example:

```
p1 = {2.7432, 0., 0.}; p2 = {-2.743199, 0., 0.};
```

`VectorAngle[]` surprisingly returns a complex result:

```
VectorAngle[p1, p2]
   3.141592653589793 - 2.1073424338879928*^-8*I
```

but using the explicit *classical* formula seems okay:

```
ArcCos[Normalize[p1].Normalize[Conjugate[p2]]]
   3.141592653589793
```

Now, consider this example:

```
p1 = {2.7432000016, 0., 0.}; p2 = {-2.743199992, 0., 0.};
```

`VectorAngle[]` does fine:

```
VectorAngle[p1, p2]
   3.141592653589793
```

but the explicit formula becomes inaccurate:

```
ArcCos[Normalize[p1].Normalize[Conjugate[p2]]]
   3.141592638688632
```

Tricky. Both can be inaccurate for nearly antipodal vectors. What to do?

Fortunately, [Velvel Kahan](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/MathH110/Cross.pdf) has us covered with a much more numerically reliable formula:

```
vecang[v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ] := Module[{n1 = Norm[v1], n2 = Norm[v2]},
       2 ArcTan[Norm[v1 n2 + n1 v2], Norm[v1 n2 - n1 v2]]]
```

which is accurate in both of the cases I gave:

```
vecang @@@ {{{2.7432, 0., 0.}, {-2.743199, 0., 0.}},
            {{2.7432000016, 0., 0.}, {-2.743199992, 0., 0.}}}
   {3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793}
```

---

### Addendum

`VectorAngle[]` now gives accurate results as of version 11.2:

```
VectorAngle @@@ {{{2.7432, 0., 0.}, {-2.743199, 0., 0.}},
                 {{2.7432000016, 0., 0.}, {-2.743199992, 0., 0.}}} // InputForm
   {3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a bug.

You get the correct result from

```
vectorAngle[vec1_, vec2_] :=
 ArcCos[vec1.vec2/(Norm[vec1] Norm[vec2])]

vectorAngle[{-2.7432000000000016`, 0.`, 
  0.`}, {2.743199999999973`, 0.`, 0.`}]

(* ==> 3.14159 *)
```

This function is just a manual implementation of the definition as stated in the documentation of [`VectorAngle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorAngle.html). Therefore, the current built-in `VectorAngle` does not appear to be implemented as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is to note that at some point, this bug in `VectorAngle` has been fixed in or before V13.2:

```
VectorAngle[
 {-2.7432000000000016`, 0.`, 0.`},
 {2.743199999999973`, 0.`, 0.`}]
(*  3.14159  *)
```

The version history in the docs does not indicated that `VectorAngle` has been changed.

Comment: Nice catch and thanks for updating. I checked that it's fixed from `v12.0.0`.