# Angle between two vectors in spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, vector-calculus, coordinate-transformation

I have two vectors:

```
H = {1, 0, π/4};
EA = {1, 0, 0};
```

Which I want to be in {r, Phi, Theta} - which would should give an angle between the two vectors as `π/4`.

However, I get `VectorAngle[N[EA], N[H]]` = 0.66577 in Mathematica.

I'm not sure if there is an issue with the coordinate system, or .... ?

Comment: *Mathematica* doesn't know that your vectors are in spherical coordinates. It's assuming that you are using rectangular (Cartesian) coordinates. Convert to rectangular coordinates first and try again.

Comment: `Apply[VectorAngle, #1 {Cos[#2] Sin[#3], Sin[#2] Sin[#3], Cos[#3]} & @@@ {EA, H}]`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Also see [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57377/245) for a pathological case where `VectorAngle` becomes inaccurate. The three answers there provide different workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this is not a problem that is easy to solve by reading the docs, because anything less than very thorough and careful reading of the docs on the subject of converting spherical to cartesian coordinates can easily lead the user astray.

A casual reading of the docs will lead one to think

```
map = CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
u = {1, 0, π/4};
v = {1, 0, 0};
VectorAngle @@ map /@ {u, v}
```

will work, but it gives

> `0`

The problem is caused by the user assuming that φ, the 2nd spherical coordinate, is latitude aka altitude, but it's not; it's declination aka polar angle. So one must use

```
VectorAngle @@ map /@ MapAt[π/2 - # &, {u, v}, {All, 2}]
```

> `π/4`