# How can I understand this short example?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

First launch kernels

```
LaunchKernels[4]

{KernelObject[5, "local"], KernelObject[6, "local"], KernelObject[7, "local"], KernelObject[8, "local"]}
```

Then I calculate This cell

```
f1 = Table[ParallelSubmit[{j}, Sum[N@Gamma[i + j], {i, 10000}]], {j, 4}];
out1=AbsoluteTiming[WaitAll[f1]];out1[[1]]
```

The output is

```
4.025230
```

But when I just set a=0

```
a = 0;
f2 = Table[ParallelSubmit[{j}, Sum[N@Gamma[a + i + j], {i, 10000}]], {j, 4}];
out2 = AbsoluteTiming[WaitAll[f2]]; out2[[1]]
```

The output

```
0.729042
```

Is much speeder then before.

The result is same

```
out1[[2]] == out2[[2]]
True
```

Why? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition `a = 0` is not being distributed among the subkernels, therefore in `f2` the `Sum` is evaluated symbolically.  After the results are returned to the master kernel `a` is substituted in.

It happens that in this case a symbolic sum is much faster:

```
ClearAll[a]

Sum[N@Gamma[i + 1], {i, 10000}] // AbsoluteTiming

Sum[N@Gamma[a + i + 1], {i, 10000}] /. a -> 0 // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.08047, 2.846544335353437*10^35659}
>
> {0.0687247, 2.8465443354*10^35659}
> ```

The reason is that in the first line `Gamma` is being computed with exact arithmetic, *then* converted to machine precision with `N`.  If we simply use `` 1` `` instead it is fast:

```
Sum[Gamma[i + 1`], {i, 10000}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0585066, 2.8465443354*10^35659}
> ```

The second case is fast because `Gamma` is does not have [`NHoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldAll.html) or similar, therefore `1` is converted to `1.` which has the same effect:

```
N @ Gamma[a + i + 1]
```

> ```
> Gamma[1. + a + i]
> ```

Reference: [Converting to machine precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7564/121)

Comment: Beat me to it... (+1)

Comment: @kale Sorry, but thank you.