# Dynamic divide as number rather than fraction

Tags: dynamic, numerics, scoping

I'm practising making `Dynamics` so I made a simple solution measurement converter but I'm having trouble getting a numerical output at `basemL/baseL`. It keeps coming out as fractional even though I've probably overdone using `N`. I've also tried doing this with `With` putting the entire `Grid` inside it but it still comes out as fractional.

```
DynamicModule[
    {baseTsp=1, baseGal=1,basemL=N[Dynamic[baseTsp*157725491/32000000]], baseL=N[Dynamic[baseGal*473176473/125000]]},
    Grid[{
        {InputField[Dynamic@baseTsp, Number,ImageSize->{50,20}, Alignment->Center],
        "Tsp  (Solution) per",
        InputField[Dynamic@baseGal, Number,ImageSize->{50,20}, Alignment->Center],
        "Gallon (Base)"},
        {InputField[basemL, Number,ImageSize->{70,20}, Alignment->Center,Enabled->False],
        "mL (Solution) per",
        InputField[baseL, Number,ImageSize->{70,20}, Alignment->Center,Enabled->False],
        "mL (Base)"},
        {InputField[N[basemL/baseL],Enabled->False],
        "per 1000 mL"}
    }, Alignment->Left]
]
```

How do I make it output as numerical?
Also if you have suggestions on how I can improve my code or better conventions using `Dynamics` please feel free to tell me.

Comment: I tried as you suggested
`{baseTsp=1, baseGal=1,basemL, baseL}` and `InputField[basemL=N[Dynamic[baseTsp*157725491/32000000]]` for `basemL` and `baseL` but it still comes out as fractional output at `basemL/baseL`.

Comment: Inside the definition of `baseml` within the `InputField` wrap the right hand side of the equal sign with `N`. That is `InputField[Dynamic[basemL = N[baseTsp*157725491/32000000]] ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different formulation than Karsten 7 proposed in a comment but similar in spirit I think:

```
DynamicModule[

 {baseTsp = 1, baseGal = 1, basemL, baseL},

 Grid[{
   {
    InputField[Dynamic[baseTsp], Number, ImageSize -> {50, 20}, 
     Alignment -> Center], "Tsp  (Solution) per", 
    InputField[Dynamic[baseGal], Number, ImageSize -> {50, 20}, 
     Alignment -> Center], "Gallon (Base)"},
   {
    InputField[Dynamic[basemL = baseTsp*157725491`/32000000`], Number, 
     ImageSize -> {70, 20}, Alignment -> Center, Enabled -> False], 
    "mL (Solution) per", 
    InputField[Dynamic[baseL = baseGal*473176473`/125000`], Number, 
     ImageSize -> {70, 20}, Alignment -> Center, Enabled -> False], "mL (Base)"},
   {
    InputField[Dynamic[basemL/baseL], Enabled -> False], "per 1000 mL"}},
  Alignment -> Left
 ]
]
```

Note the use of backtick to enter machine precision numbers.  See:

- [Converting to machine precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7564/121)

Comment: This works, thanks. Is putting variable definition inside `Grid` rather than at declaration considered convention or are there computational differences? After playing with the code it seemed that the `Dynamic` during definition of `basemL` and `baseL` was what was causing the output to be fractional.

Comment: @Isho I would not say it is a convention, rather it just seems appropriate here.  A `Dynamic` expression *must* be displayed in the Notebook for it to have effect, so if we are going to use `Dynamic` in this way displaying it inside the `Grid` makes sense.  An alternative is to make the entire `Grid` expression `Dynamic`, i.e. `Dynamic[Grid[ . . . ]]` but *that* would cause extra evaluation I believe as the entire `Grid` would be redrawn when a value is changed, rather than only the `InputField`.