# How to create an Identity matrix and replace the ''1''s with n which n is the elements' row or column number?

Tags: matrix, replacement

I want to create a `n` by `n` Identity matrix and replace the ones with  `n π^2`. `NOS` is three here (it is a number). The code I have written for this doesn't work.

```
Kin = IdentityMatrix[NOS]

n = 1; m = 1; While[n == m && n < NOS &&  m < NOS, 
 Kin[[n, m]] -> n π^2; n++; m++]
```

I want

```
Kin[[1, 1]]== π^2
Kin[[2, 2]]==2 π^2
```

and so on. Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: try `Pi^2 DiagonalMatrix[Range[NOS]] `

Comment: @klgr Thanks a lot, It works

Answer (score 9):

It is far faster to make the multiplication by a vector and *then* convert to a diagonal matrix, rather than building a full matrix and multiplying after:

```
DiagonalMatrix[π^2 Range[3]]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \pi ^2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 \pi ^2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 \pi ^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Even faster is to build a sparse array, which is done by applying [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) before (inside) [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix.html).  With this formulation multiplicaiton after is fast because only specified elements (the diagonal) are actually multiplied.

```
π^2 DiagonalMatrix[Range[1000]];                // RepeatedTiming // First
DiagonalMatrix[π^2 Range[1000]];                // RepeatedTiming // First
π^2 DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray @ Range[1000]];  // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.434
>
> 0.01
>
> 0.000647
> ```

The examples above preserve the diagonals in Symbolic form.  If machine reals<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7564/121)</sup> are OK:

```
π^2` DiagonalMatrix[Range[1000]];                // RepeatedTiming // First
DiagonalMatrix[π^2` Range[1000]];                // RepeatedTiming // First
π^2` DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray @ Range[1000]];  // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0040
>
> 0.00174
>
> 0.0000231
> ```

Reference:

- [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/121)

Comment: Can you explain why the `SparseArray[]` solution is faster?

Comment: @AnjanKumar It is a much smaller expression being created, here about 1/144 the size of the dense array.  Because of the use of exact `π^2` the array cannot be packed (in the plain case), so fast library operations cannot be used.  ``π^2` DiagonalMatrix[Range[1000]];`` (note the backtick) takes only 0.00371 on my machine because everything remains packed and fast library functions are used.

Comment: I should add the note that there is an *undocumented* syntax for directly producing a sparse diagonal matrix: `DiagonalMatrix[π^2 Range[3], 0, 3, SparseArray]`

Answer (score 6):

```
NOS = 3; 

π^2 DiagonalMatrix[Range[NOS]] 
π^2 Range[NOS] IdentityMatrix[NOS]
MapIndexed[π^2 #2[[1]] # &, IdentityMatrix[NOS], {2}]
ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[NOS], {i_, i_} :> (i π^2)]
Block[{i = 1}, IdentityMatrix[NOS] /. 1 :> (π^2 i++)]
```

all give

> {{π^2, 0, 0}, {0, 2 π^2, 0}, {0, 0, 3 π^2}}

Answer (score 4):

here is another way using `Unitize`

```
π^2 Table[i (1 - Unitize[Range[1000] - i]), {i, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming 
  (* {0.552622, Null} *)
```

and with `SparseArray` alone:

```
π^2 SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> i , {1000, 1000}];//AbsoluteTiming
  (* {0.00134081, Null} *)
```

Borrowing the backtick from @Mr.Wizard significantly improves the answer

```
π^2` Table[i (1 - Unitize[Range[1000] - i]), {i, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0230811, Null} *)


π^2` SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> i, {1000, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000165618, Null} *)
```

Comment: Which version are you using?  For the first line I get 0.43793 and for the second 0.000658.  What timings do you get for the six lines in my answer, please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for picking it out. I think for the first one i used the timing from `Range[100]` rather than 1000. I just updated it

Comment: `Table` just seems unnecessarily baroque and honestly I'd leave it out if I were you, but +1 for the concise `SparseArray` form.  It's not *quite* as fast as `DiagonalMatrix` with a sparse argument but I doubt it matters.  FWIW `SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> i Pi^2, {1000, 1000}]` also works.